# Labeling multi-line equation not working as expected

Tags: equations, amsmath, labels

My aim is to set the label of the following equation to right as usual. The difference is that here I have two lines which messes this labeling up.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{weight} 
\omega_{x_R} = \begin{cases}
   {1 \over N, & \text{if } N \ge 1 
   \\ 1, & \text{otherwise }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

See the following:

[image]

Comment: after any error the pdf output is just intended as a debugging aid not to be usable.You are missing  `\end{cases}`  and other errors: `Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 7.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.7    {1 \over N, &
                     \text{if } N \ge 1
? `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ignore errors, the PDF is not usable after any error. You are missing `\end{cases}` here. Also `\over` is not LaTeX and should never be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{weight} 
\omega_{x_R} = \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{N}, & \text{if } N \ge 1 \\
    1, & \text{otherwise }
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```